# Cloning of domain objects with javafx properties

Tags: java, clone, javafx-8

I have some domain objects in a javafx application that I'm trying to clone using the [Java deep cloning library](https://code.google.com/p/cloning/). If I add a listener to one of the javafx properties the cloning fails with a `NoClassDefFoundError`. I have tried telling the cloner to insert null instead of clone for the listener classes, but this ha no effect:

```
com.rits.cloning.Cloner cloner = new com.rits.cloning.Cloner();
cloner.nullInsteadOfClone(ChangeListener.class, InvalidationListener.class);
```

Does anyone have any tips?

**Example code:**

Domain object with javafx property:

```
public class ItemType implements Serializable {

private final LongProperty id;
private final StringProperty description;

public ItemType() {
    this.id = new SimpleLongProperty();
    this.description = new SimpleStringProperty();
}

public Long getId() {
    return this.id.get();
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id.set(id);
}

public LongProperty idProperty() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return this.description.get();
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description.set(description);
}

public StringProperty descriptionProperty() {
    return this.description;
}
```

Code that succeeds:

```
ItemType itemtype = new ItemType(1L, "test");
cloner.deepClone(itemtype);
```

Code that fails:

```
ItemType itemtype = new ItemType(1L, "test");
itemtype.idProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

    });
cloner.deepClone(itemtype);
```

Comment: worksforme (no exception with the second snippet in a quick test) - please consider posting a SSCCE that demonstrates the failure.

Comment: thats what I thought I did..

Comment: ..but extracting this code into a new java application, it works. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The reason for this error seems to be that the anonymous class(the listener) is created inside a javafx-controller. This controller has some TableColumns with listeners, and apparently these are included in the clone somehow. Moving the listener to a separate class fixes the problem...

Comment: glad you found it - and a major part of why an SSCCE helps so much :-)